# python :- can't start new thread

Tags: python

i need to know why when i run the below code it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\moksh\Desktop\moksh.py", line 29, in <module>
    server_B_thread.start()
error: can't start new thread
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time
import SocketServer
import socket 

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "%s wrote: " % self.client_address[0]
        print 'Connection from',self.client_address[0]
        print self.data
        self.request.send(self.data.upper())

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    PORT = 1000
    while PORT <1900: 
       server_B = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
       server_B_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_B.serve_forever)
       server_B_thread.setDaemon(True)
       server_B_thread.start()
       PORT +=1

    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to start 900 threads, and probably hitting a limit on the OS. I don't know what you're trying to do, but I would look into [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), which will probably have more options for running a high volume TCP server.

Comment: thanks dan,  i need to write a program to listen to all ports (65535)

Comment: Generally, ports 1024 and lower are reserved. I question the task you're trying to solve that requires that many open ports....but Twisted ought to help, since you can bind to multiple ports without using that many processes.